# Geometry: Angle Pair Relationships

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the figure, $KJ$ and $KL$ are opposite rays $(~\angle1 = \angle2~)$ and $KM$ bisects $\angle NKL$.

If $m\angle JKN = 8x + 2$ and $m\angle MKL = 3x + 5$, what is $m\angle MKN$?

So far, I have $m\angle JKN + 2(m\angle MKL) = 180$

Answer (score 1):

*(1) m∠NKM = m∠MKL*

You know, as you said, that *m∠JKN + 2(m∠MKL) = 180*, which means:

*8x+2 + 2*(3x + 5) = 180 -> 14x + 12 = 180 -> 14x = 168 -> (2) x = 12*

From (1) + (2):

*m∠NKM = m∠MKL = 3x + 5 = 3*12 + 5 = 41*